# Jenkins Execute shell script suddenly requires full path to binary

Tags: jenkins

I had a test job. It ran

```
date
```

Using the Execute shell functionality, for months.

Today users complaining about everything, I run my job again, and I find that I have to

```
/bin/date
```

for the same job to run successfully.... I'm at loss, any advise appreciated.

Comment: Shell is executed on a remote host? Anything changed on remote host?Maybe PATH variable is changed?

Comment: Please have a basic understanding of Jenkins before posting. Execute shell is a standard thing in Jenkins that anyone who has used Jenkins would have come across. Thanks.

Comment: Like Jurica stated correctly, one potential failure is that you run your shell command on different Jenkins nodes that have different PATH settings or that your shell profile has changed thus resulting in different date binaries being executed.